# Matlab to Excel and vice versa

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to run Matlab in parallel with another program. Matlab will run as long as the other program is running and a series of if loops determine what part of the code is needed.

Some of the equations to work out the current value include the value of that variable from the last iteration, eg

`T_brick(ii) = T_brick(ii-1) + T_change(ii);`

This was fine when I was using for loops, but the two programs won't run in sync when I use for loops and so I am trying if loops, where I hold the value of T_brick(ii-1) somewhere and read it during the current iteration. What I have done is as follows

```
T_brick_previous = xlsread('worksheet1', A1)
T_brick = T_brick_previous + T_change
xlswrite('worksheet1', A1)
```

However, the value it ends up reading in for T_brick_previous is zero and I cannot understand why. Could anybody provide some advice on the possible issue or possibly even another way to do this?

Edit: In one iteration, I am hoping to read in the previous value of T_brick and after calculations have been performed, update it to a current value. Currently Matlab is reading in the previous value and writing the current value to the same cell in Excel.

I am still trying to get it to run on Matlab alone, and have not been able to as Matlab is reading in T_brick_previous as NaN

Comment: Are you just using Excel to store a value externally? what is the other programme you are running in parallel with Matlab?

Comment: As well as to store those values, I also use Excel to determine a number of initial conditions as it is a simpler user interface than the other options available. The program running in parallel is Energy Plus, a building simulation program